# I want to break line in textarea with shift+enter

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

```
 <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" ID="txtComment" runat="server"
  Columns="70" CssClass="commentTxt" onkeypress="getNextElement(this.id,event)"/>
```

This is my textbox with textarea .

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function getNextElement(id, e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                console.log(e);
                if (e.shiftKey) {

                    return true;
                }
                debugger
                $(":input[id=" + id + "]").next().click();
            }

        }


    </script>
```

this is my function.
When i press shift+enter then it will go to new line in text box

```
example : - hello
            hi
```

but when i store this text into database then it will store as `hello hi` but i want

```
hello
hi
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Are you sure it's storing it in the database without the new-lines?  In SQL Server, if you edit or open a table, the grid will not show new-lines... but if you do a `select [textfield] from [mytable]` statement and send the results to `text` (instead of `grid`) you'll probably find the new-lines are actually there

Comment: Also, if you're displaying the value from the database directly into HTML, then it's likely that you need to replace the new-lines with `<br/>` tags... or display it using something like `<pre>` tag

Comment: but how can i strore <br/> with this texts?

Comment: you can either replace the new-lines with `<br/>` BEFORE you save the text into the database, or you replace them AFTER you retrieve them from the database.  I would recommend afterwards, because you'll want to do a HTML Encoding on the text before display, and that will also encode the `<br/>` tags if you're not careful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
txtComment.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>")
```

so when you give enter it replace with `<br/>` so you will get output as follow

```
hello<br/>hi
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a bit confused. If you are saying that the line breaks are not getting saved to the database then you will need to expand on your question a little bit and demonstrate how you are saving the data. But, if what you are saying that you CAN'T see the line breaks in tools such as MS SQL Server Management Studio, then don't stress about it because the Query Analyzer's results pane is supposed to be used to preview data with limited formatting...it means that you will not see the line break character(\n)

Comment: how can i store \n character when i insert those texts.. ?